# How to align list-elements of a drop-down menu next to each other

Tags: html, css, list, navbar, multiple-columns

I'm building a multi-level navbar with CSS and HTML, and I want to have a drop-down ul-list with multiple columns next to each other. Normally, the drop-down-list would be one long column with li-elements, but I want to wrap li-elements around the column after a certain boundary. Can you help me?

I've tried working with `display: flex;` on the ul-list, but nothing did really work.

**CSS**

```css
ul {
   list-style:none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #333;
}

ul li {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   background: #333;
}

li ul {
   display: none;
}

ul li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 1em;
   text-decoration: none;
   white-space: nowrap;
   color: #fff;
}

.main-navigation li ul li {
   border-top: 0;
}

ul ul ul {
   left: 100%;
   top: 0;
}

ul:before, ul:after {
   display: table;
   content: "";
}

ul:after {
   clear: both;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li { float: none; }
```

**HTML**

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">First Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">column1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">column3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, please close your `a` tags

Comment: Why don't you wrap the same column elements in a different ul element? e.g. column1 elements in different ul, column2 elements in different ul and so on? Then you can just set the children ul to be displayed on the same row...

Comment: @metaDesign thank's for pointing out!

Comment: @n1kkou I've actually tried doing this, but it didn't get along with my CSS and just created a whole mess...

Answer (score 2):

Use `column-count`

> The column-count CSS property breaks an element's content into the specified number of columns.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

```css
ul.col {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="col">
  <li><a href="#">column1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">column3</a></li>
</ul>
```